# Notification for HidesBarsOnSwipe iOS NavigationController

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios8, uinavigationcontroller

I am making use of the HidesBarsOnSwipe property on UINavigationController, its working as expected but i would like to be notified when this action occurs. I have spent a good deal of time searching for a method to do so but have found nothing relevant. Can anyone point me in the correct direction?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a property on `UINavigationController` called `barHideOnSwipeGestureRecognizer`. You can add a target to that gesture recognizer that will be invoked every time the user swipes to hide/show the bars, like so:

```
self.navigationController?.barHideOnSwipeGestureRecognizer.addTarget(self, action: "didTriggerBarAppearanceUpdate")
```

Read more about this gesture recognizer in the [UINavigationController docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationController/barHideOnSwipeGestureRecognizer). Apple notes a few things can't do with this gesture recognizer.